# Model binding in python - automatically turn parameters passed in an http post request into fields of a class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Do you know any way to safely and automatically turn parameters passed in an http post request into fields of a class?
I'm not using django, I'm working with webapp2

I sort of implemented this feature in the following manner:
Obviously this is a naive way for a really small application. Suggestions for more solid system will be much appreciated.

I created a list of dictionaries where I store informations about fields I want to build a  for

```
form_fields = [{'placeholder': 'First Name',
           'attribute_name': 'first_name',
           'icon': 'icon-user',
           'has_errors': lambda x: "Name required" if len(x) <= 2 or x == "Name" else None },...]
```

In the same dictionary I stored additional informations I need for form templating and a function I call to validate input

In the post(self): handler I'm doing something like this:

```
        errors = []
        my_model = MyModel()
        for field in form_fields:
            value = self.request.get(field['attribute_name'])
            setattr(my_model, field['attribute_name'], value)
            error = field['has_errors'](value)
            if error: errors.append(error)

        if len(errors) == 0:           
            my_model.put()
            self.redirect('/somewhere')
        else:
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('template.html')
            context = {
                'form_fields': form_fields,
                'my_model': my_model,
                'errors': errors
            }
            self.response.write(template.render(context))
```

The view is straightforward:

```
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{error}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
<form method="post">
<fieldset>
{% for element in form_fields %}
<i class="{{element.icon}}"></i>
<input type="text" name="{{element.attribute_name}}" onfocus="if(this.value == '{{element.placeholder}}') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = '{{element.placeholder}}'; }" 
       value="{{my_model[element.attribute_name] if my_model is defined else element.placeholder}}" />
{% endfor %}

<div class="clear">
    <button id="submit" type="submit">OK <i class="icon-caret-right buttonArrow"></i></button>
</div>
```

Obviously this is a naive way for a really small application. Suggestions for more solid system will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the builtin function `setattr` can help you:

```
class X(object):
    pass

x = X()
setattr(x, 'a', 2)
print x.a  # returns 2
```

Documentation for [setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr).

Comment: You can check an attribute exists with `hasattr(x, 'a')`